# Data frame reshape based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following problem that I quite struggle to solve:

I have a data frame looking like:

```
row1 = c(55.7, NA, NA, "inf", 4.19, 99, 4, 15, 16, NA, 13, 0.1, 0.8, 51, NA, 44)
row2 = c(13, 1, 81, 6, NA, 0.3, NA, NA, 1.4, 89, NA, NA, 2.1, 99, 0.5, NA)
df = data.frame(row1, row2)
df = as.data.frame(t(df))
```

The first problem is that I need to change values "inf" to numerical == 100.

All I use does not help.
This creates additional NAs:

```
data[data =="inf"] = 100
```

This just don't work:

```
data[is.na(data)] = "Skip"
```

I expect it is because of data types but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

The second problem is more complex. I need to transform the data frame to match the highest values columns with lowest one columns to get somethink like this:

```
row3 = c("row1","V4", "V12")
row4 = c("row1", "V6", "V13")
df2 = data.frame(row3, row4)
df2 = t(df2)
```

And so on for all rows and columns.

The problem is that I cannot even find an approach how to solve this task, if you can give me a direction that will be extremely valuable.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem try to convert your values to character:

```
df[]<-lapply(df, as.character)
df[df =="inf"] = "100"
```

Then convert it back to factor:

```
df[]<-lapply(df, as.factor)
```